# Sending php tags in a string

Tags: php, string, file-io

I've created a script which takes names from my db and for each name creates a .php file for them. However I would like to fill this file already with a (php) header since letters such as ë é and ú are not shown correctly without it.

So far i've got this:

```
<?php
// ... 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
$file = "Map/" . $row['name'] . ".php";
$fh = fopen("$file", "w+");
if($fh==false){
die("unable to create file");
}
echo "$file created <br/>";
$stringData = "<center><h1>". $row['name'] . "</h1></center>\n
No text available just yet.";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
}
fclose($fh);
?>
```

What i would like to do now is place the following line of code even before the center tag:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15'); ?>
```

As i retrieve the stored text from the .php file using an ajax request (with JQuery), the header must be in the file in order to be able to show those special letters. Thus my question: how can i place this line of code in each file, rather than php just executing it? (Or if this can be done easier, how so?)

#### Edit after comment:

After the script has run i would like to have a file that looks like this:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15'); ?>
<center><h1>Chocolate</h1></center>
No text available yet.
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "how can i place this line of code in each file, rather than php just executing it."

Comment: please use css rather than <center>

Comment: It's just for illustrative purpose :) @cdhowie see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this, immediately after opening the file:

```
fwrite($fh, "<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15'); ?>\n");
```

PHP is smart enough to know that `?>` is not an end-PHP marker when it appears in a string literal.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `meta` tag in `head` section of your HTML, it tells the browser which character encoding is used:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15"/>`

By the way, if you're starting a new project, think about using the UTF-8 encoding. It often is a better choise than ISO-* because it allows all Unicode characters (all characters of the whole world) with one encoding.

Comment: A "better" choice is relative. If the encoding *is* `ISO-8859-15`, `UTF-8` would not be better but just plain wrong.

Comment: Maybe I should say: "If you are starting a new project, then use UTF-8".

Comment: I'd say that sounds better ;)

Comment: Didn't do the job. I'm getting � sympbols when i only have the meta tag.

Comment: @Gooey, so change `UTF-8` to `ISO-8859-15`. The `UTF` case was only a suggestion.

Comment: @Gooey, can you show to us, how the whole HTML file (with this meta tag) looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Please ask about your real question; not about what you assume could be the solution. As far as I understood it the question should read something along: "How to set a specific file encoding via PHP?"

If your output is an HTML file use a META-tag as suggested by Glibnes.

If the written file is plain text, you should convert your text to UTF-8 and `fwrite()` it to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following stringData instead of the above

```
$stringData = '<?php header(\'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15\'); ?><center><h1>'. $row['name'] . "</h1></center>\n
No text available just yet.";
```

As you are writing it in .php file. It should execute the header function.